# How to create an object with user defined name in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables

```
 var a= "user passed name/ value from run time" // assume it is: xValue
 var xValue="some value" //x must be value of a
 //ie "user passed name/ value from run time" = some value
```

How can this be achieved where x in the value of a?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

Comment: _was awful_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Comment: I'm struggling to see what `window.prompt` has to do with the question, but then I'm struggling with the question too.. :)

Comment: well technically `const x = window.prompt("What is your name?);` is getting a user passed name/value, and saving it into `x` :) But yes the question is incoherent.

Comment: I know how to take value from prompt. I need to create a new variable with this value. @George

Comment: You can assign values with `=`. e.g. `x = a`

Comment: @George but name of variable x is not x acctually. It is given by user. I am giving it a hypothetical xValue value.

Comment: So, you want a user to specify the name of a variable? Why? This sounds like an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve?
...
`var myObject = { [userValue]: 'some value' };`

Comment: Look at my answer . That was what I wanted. I don't know why you didn't got the question. @George

Comment: I would call that a dynamic name not a user passed name.

Comment: Value from run time means the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a="xValue";
this[a]="some value"; //window[a] if scope of this is not global.
console.log(xValue);
```

This is what I wanted. After a whole day of struggle I figured it out.